# Construct example of non 2-connected graph with a given property

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I've been asked to give an example of a graph in which each vertex has at least degree 2017 and which is not 2-connected.

At first, I was thinking about a fully-connected graph on 2017 vertices which is 2016-connected. But this answer is wrong since any n-connected graph is also n-1, n-2, ..., 1-connected.

Could somebody give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: Remind yourself what it means to be $1$-connected but not $2$-connected.  How about having a big blob of things on the left and a big blob of things on the right and a single edge connecting these two blobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take two copies of $K_{2018}$ and join them by one edge.